# Add to cart - Loader spins until timeout, but product was added quickly

Tags: cart, ajax, shopping-cart, timeout

Magento Community 1.9.2.4

Systems were working until an extension from BSS Commerce (Defer Javascript) was installed and a couple of other internal small changes were made.
**EDIT** 
The BSS Commerce replied stating that it is unlikely that after removing the extension, that the fault lies with their code as it doesn't update  or re-write any other code.

It may have been that this was the trigger for some underlying issue that was simply waiting to appear...?
**EDIT**

Am having trouble tracking down exactly which element is causing the fault.

Defer Javascript has now been disabled and then removed (via FTP - the exact same way it was installed) - all cache flushed, compiler now disabled for testing purposes.

Only other changes are;
Cookie path and cookie domain fields empty (previously were "/" for path and "domain.co.uk" for Cookie Domain
These were changed as we started getting the login redirect loop problem on the backend. Not sure if that is linked to the defer javascript problem.

SSL certificate was installed by the server host company - everything appeared to be functioning correctly after this though.

Zend full page cache now disabled during testing.

Site is effectively dead - as customers get bored of waiting and leave!

Adding a product to the cart shows the AJAX loader spinning endlessly, but if a user clicks in the background - they find that the product has been added to the cart. The cart hasn't updated on the page, but if a user clicks the cart - or changes pages the cart updates with the item in there.

Prior to the changes, everything was working fine.

Anyone able to give a couple of suggestions as to what the cause might be \ how to track it down \ similar issues & how they fixed it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally traced the root cause of the errors.

For others in a similar situation check the following, as this was what the problem was for me.

System -> Configuration -> MagentoTheme -> Ajaxcart Super : Using SSL (Set to YES)

I have an SSL redirect in effect, so any user that types http://www.example.com would be brought to https://example.com
For some reason this was the sole reason the configurable items wouldn't get added to the cart properly, but simple items could.

Hope it helps :)